# PHP 7 подготавливаемые запросы

Tags: php7

Ошибка возникает на $sql. Вроде бы всё правильно указано. Переменные вставляются из input.

```
$login=$_POST['login'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$sql=$mysqli->prepare("select * from users where 'login'=? and 'password'=?");
$sql->bind_param('ss',$login,$password);
$sql->execute();
$zapros = $sql->get_result();
```

Ошибка:
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in  on line 6

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in :6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in  on line 6

Comment: Вызов функции `prepare()` у объекта `null`. Ваш $mysqli равен null

Comment: в общем надо бы создать объект
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_database');